# How to stack divs vertically with CSS or Vuetify independently from the divs in the side?

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I want my divs to be on top of each other without following the height of the div by the side.

Currently my divs are being displayed like this:

[image]

I don't want that white space between the divs just because one of divs is bigger. It should be something like this:

[image]

I'm using Vuetify, so the solution may use vuetify classes or pure CSS.

EDIT:

For better explanation,the desired behaviour is pretty much like this:

[image]

Source: https://starkwang.github.io/vue-virtual-collection/demo/dist/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with `column-count` css. I tried this with chrome for not breaking the div between the columns.

```css
.columns {
  column-count: 3;
  width: 100%; 
  
}

.column {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; 
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">

  <div class="column" style="height: 100px;">
      box1
  </div>
  
  <div class="column" style="height: 130px;">
     box2
  </div>
  
  <div class="column" style="height: 80px;">
    box3
  </div>
  
  <div class="column" style="height: 150px;">
    box4
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="normal"> Normal Text </div>
```

Comment: Is it possible make the box sequence follow horizontally? Like filling one box per column, then two per column and so on... keeping that aspect

Comment: In my opinion, It is straightforward. If you are using bootstrap, with .row and .col-[1-12] you can structure the data in the way you want.

Comment: I'm using material design, which has those feature such as row and col. I mean showing this way https://starkwang.github.io/vue-virtual-collection/demo/dist/index.html So I can interate as many as I want in the page, and the most recent blocks appear at the top

Answer (score 0):

One way to achive a layout like this is using [css grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.item.big-item{
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="item">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="item big-item">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        4
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="item">
        5
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well, it would be nice to know reason for a down vote to improve next time.

Comment: ....you have asked in for a **pure CSS** solution in your question. @samir-haddad

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't downvote. I actually just upvoted because it seems to work, I will test it later

Comment: Is it possible make the box sequence follow horizontally? Like filling one box per column, then two per column and so on... keeping that aspect

Comment: yep, for each  `.item` class, you can use `display:flex;` and `flex-flow:row;` to achieve this. Something like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/nidhingeorgejoseph/8vmtLar1/

Comment: I mean that way https://starkwang.github.io/vue-virtual-collection/demo/dist/index.html  So I can interate as many as I want in the page, and the most recent blocks apear at the top

Answer (score 0):

Understanding the framework classes is more important than coming up with "fixes" using CSS.

Check the grid documentation and how the rows and columns work.

you can put these blocks in different rows and it'll be aligned:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid grid-list-lg>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12 sm12 md4>
          <div class="content div1"></div>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs12 sm12 md4>
          <div class="content div2"></div>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs12 sm12 md4>
          <div class="content div3"></div>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12 sm12 md4>
          <div class="content div1"></div>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs12 sm12 md4>
          <div class="content div2"></div>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs12 sm12 md4>
          <div class="content div3"></div>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/fabiozanchi/pen/RzVYMZ

Comment: Thanks for awsering, I think you misunderstand me. This is how my divs are being displayed now. I want it to be like the other image I posted, without that blank space.

Comment: I mean something like this https://starkwang.github.io/vue-virtual-collection/demo/dist/index.html